# Login to a Web Application with Powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, web

trying to get information from a Web Application automaticly. To be able to an autorization is required. Thought I had found a promising way, my Code:

---

```
$nvidiaLogin = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://"FQDNServer":8080/licserver/securerest_view.action' -SessionVariable serverSession

$nvidiaLoginForm=$nvidiaLogin.Forms[0]

$nvidiaLoginForm.Fields["SecurerestPageForm_securerest_userName"]="username"
$nvidiaLoginForm.Fields["SecurerestPageForm_securerest_password"]="password"

$page = "http://"FQDNServer":8080/" + $nvidiaLoginForm.Action

$result=Invoke-WebRequest $page -WebSession $serverSession -Method Post -body $nvidiaLoginForm.Fields

$result.RawContent
```

---

The idea is to get the information of the login page.
Then the form of the login page.
After this fill the form elements with username and password.
And last execute the login.

But what should be the login. is something i dont understand, for example $nvidiaLoginForm.Action is:

/licserver/DownloadSecurerestToken.action;jsessionid=E6BF4357E33D517F2BB8F80E9AA51C2C

With this action the script can not login. And the form doesnt have another action.

So my question is there something I'm missing or should I do it completly different.

Comment: If `$nvidiaLoginForm.Action = '/licserver/DownloadSecurerestToken.action;jsessionid=E6BF4357E33D517F2BB8F80E9AA51C2C'` then would `$page = "http://"FQDNServer":8080/" + $nvidiaLoginForm.Action` result in a double forward slash in the URL.

I think your approach should be OK, but it depends on the implementation of the website and the form you are trying to submit. Have to tried to debug it with for example the Developer tools of Chrome?

Comment: I used the Chrome Developer tools a lot, but I have no real idea of what i have to been looking for. At least with the Developer tools, I can see how the html respone should be, if I login to the webpage directly without the powershell code. In my logic my code is missing the login method, i mean it should be "$nvidiaLoginForm.Action", but obviously it's something different.